# Run two classes simultaneously

Tags: java

I am trying to understand multi-threaded execution in Java. I want to have a "controller" class A and an "execute in parallel" class B. Logically, I want to have a new object of class A start a new object of class B executing in a separate thread.

Should I make class B extend the Thread class, or is there a more currently accepted way of doing this.  Here is some very crude pseudo code below.

```
public class A {
...
  Class B()  // call class B    
...
}

public class B extends Thread {
  public void run(){
    //some code
  }
}
```

Comment: You need two thread, read about java Threads

Comment: `"Actually, I read about Threads in Java and I made two classes using the same logic above but it didn't work with me."` -- to get better answers, please provide more information since "didn't work with me" tells us little about your problem. Please show your code that didn't work. Please only show ***real*** code, not "kind-of, sort-of" code like you've posted above. Please explain how it didn't work, what errors you might see, what misbehaviors your encountered. Remember that details and accuracy are *very* important.

Comment: You need to read an introductory tutorial on Java. Try Oracle's Java trails.

Comment: Your syntax, and your understanding of Java concepts, is pretty confused.  The compiler does not call a class.  Rather, the program creates an object to be an instance of a class, and then calls that object's methods.  `Class B()` is not anything close to the correct Java syntax for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't what you meant by `Class B()`. If you mean it execute `run` method of `Class B`. Try something like below.

```
public class A {

     public static void someMethod(){
         B b = new B();
         b.start();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       someMethod();
    }
}

public class B extends Thread{
    public void run()
    {
      //logic comes here
    }
}
```

However extending thread is not always suggested because you can't extend more than one class.

You can implement Runnable interface this allows B to extend any class and also implement other interfaces.

```
public class A {
     public void someMethod(){
         B b = new B();
         Thread t = new Thread(b);
         t.start()
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        someMethod();
     }
}

//Now below class can extend any other class
public class B implements Runnable{
    public void run()
    {
      //logic comes here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should execute `B` like this:

```
B b=new B(); 
b.start();
```

this will execute the `run` method and continue running simultaneously

Comment: Please mention something about the relative merits of extending Thread vs. implementing Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

The modern paradigm for creating a class whose objects you want to run in one or more parallel execution sessions is to:

1. Create the class and have it implement the marker interface `Runnable`
2. Create a new Thread from your Runnable
3. Start your new parallel activity by calling the start method on your Thread

   ```
   Runnable myRunnable = new Parallel(arguments);
   Thread workerThread= new Thread(myRunnable);
   //now do the work
   workerThread.start();
   ```

When you have a class that implements Runnable, it must override a method run().